# I would like to build a partial mirror, I like the look of debpartial-mirror, but it looks abandonded, recommendations for a mirror tool?

Tags: apt, software-recommendation, mirrors

I would like to build a partial mirror, I like the look of debpartial-mirror, but it looks abandonded, recommendations for a mirror tool?

https://projetos.ossystems.com.br/wiki/debpartial-mirror

I choose debpartial-mirror because I can mirror only sections and subsections. Other tools such as debmirror and apt-mirror did not seem to have this functionality.

I've read http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

Does anyone have other recommendations for a partial mirror? Can you tell me what happened to debpartial-mirror?

Comment: I'd like to mention that we settled on using reprepro to do partial mirroring based on filter expressions. Yes, the filter expressions can be huge, but the tool seems to work well.

Answer (score 8):

A little late, but I think this is might be useful to someone.

```
debmirror -v --method=http -a amd64 --no-check-gpg --exclude='/*' --include='/regex' /path/to/mirror
```

this basically excludes all packages except those matchin the regex. multiple include= arguments can be given

Comment: I also added the following options: `-d precise,precise-security,precise-updates`, `--no-source` (to avoid downloading source packages), `--progress` (since I was running it interactively) and `--rsync-extra=none` (to avoid any RSYNC operations if you only have HTTP access). An example include would be `--include='/debian-keyring.*$'`