# How to set up a local Ubuntu Xenial repository using apt-cacher-ng for later network installation?

Tags: system-installation, preseed, apt-mirror, localrepository, apt-cacher-ng

I would like to know how to setup apt-cacher-ng for .deb caching during a system installation of Ubuntu server 64bits dvd. I want to install other machines after repository setup via preseed. I've tried installing apt-cacher-ng in a server and pointing to this cache in an installation process with no success: installation was able to use apt-cacher as proxy but cacher didn't cached anything.

Comment: You could make a partial mirror, if that's what you want: [I would like to build a partial mirror, I like the look of debpartial-mirror, but it looks abandonded, recommendations for a mirror tool?](http://askubuntu.com/q/261253) That would avoid the 80GB download.

Comment: How can I use it to download only the necessary packages for a desktop installation(those present in installation media)?  I don't know what packages to download neither(they're not obvious from installation media). I've searched for .deb's in installation media and found only a few(24 files).

Comment: Use a caching proxy (`apt-cacher-ng`) instead of a mirror. Then perform an installation once with it so that it caches the stuff

Comment: @muru then should I use [network installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/16.04/) media for installation?

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto not necessarily. I assumed you wanted to save traffic for the updates downloaded while installing. What's the actual use case here?

Comment: @muru I want to establish a local repository for network installation through kickstart or preseed inside a corporation. So I should have a webserver with both packages(repo) and kickstart/preseed files. After a boot with netboot cd-rom or PXE I want to install Ubuntu to several machines. I already do that for RedHat, I'm wandering to know if this can be done for Ubuntu and how.

Comment: @ThiagoRiderAugusto you've already said that, but what will you be installing? If there's too much variety in installations, a mirror might be worth the 100GB. Then consider looking into provisioning tools like fog, or foreman. If not, then yes, the Netinst + preseed + apt-cacher is just fine. We used to use that, and still keep it around as a backup.

Comment: @muru, Thanks! I'm limiting installation to packages in stock Ubuntu Desktop media plus a few more apps. I was in doubt on how to know which packages should I keep in my repo. My first approach leads to extracting packages from Ubuntu media, and another possible one was downloading packages from a mirror. I'm considering using the proposed solution: Netinst + preseed + apt-cacher.